# How can I bring the keyboard into front automatically on a viewflipper?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, viewflipper

I have an activity with many viewflippers and want to bring the keyboard of an edittext into front automatically. When I start the activity it works once, logically. With this:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or this in manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

So how can I get this when activity is already started and get back to the viewflipper with the edittext?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

***Call this method when you want to show keyboard***

```
public void showSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to do an action when you press the enter key on keyboard?